# Reference a value within same "row" in Java enum

Tags: java

I have an enum a I would like set a value (exampleValue) based on another value (size). Of course this does not work, because I can't use this in a static context.

```
private enum FIELDS {
    FIELD_2("Field 1", 1, 8, StringUtils.leftPad("A", this.getSize(), "X")),
    FIELD_3("Field 2", 2, 7, StringUtils.leftPad("A", this.getSize(), "X")) ,
    FIELD_4("Field 3", 3, 9, StringUtils.leftPad("A", this.getSize(), "X"));
    
    private final String description;
    private final int number;
    private final int size;
    private final String exampleValue;
    
    FIELDS(String description, int number, int size, String exampleValue) {
      this.description = description;
      this.number = number;
      this.size = size;
      this.exampleValue = exampleValue;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
      return description;
    }
    
    public int getNumber() {
      return number;
    }

    public int getSize() {
      return size;
    }

    public String getExampleValue() {
      return exampleValue;
    }
}
```

But is there a clean Java-esque way to do it?

Comment: Don't make it a constructor parameter. Set it within the constructor, because at that point you know what `size` is. `this.exampleValue = StringUtils.leftPad("A", size, "X");` if you need different "A" or "X", you can pass them as constructor parameters

Comment: What do you mean with "pass them as constructor parameters"? Make more "columns" with e. g. exampleChar and paddingChar?

Comment: Yes, if they are not static, you make a constructor like `FIELDS(String description, int number, int size, String exampleChar, String paddingChar)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invoke a getter for size *before* the instance of `FIELDS` enum is constructed.

However, it is possible to implement an overloaded constructor to populate `exampleValue` depending on the `size` parameter to get rid of multiple calls to `StringUtils.leftPad`:

```java
public enum FIELDS {
// enum values and fields

    FIELDS(String description, int number, int size) {
      this(description, number, size, StringUtils.leftPad("A", size, "X"));
    }

    FIELDS(String description, int number, int size, String exampleValue) {
      this.description = description;
      this.number = number;
      this.size = size;
      this.exampleValue = exampleValue;
    }
// ... getters
}
```